# Localizations for abc_* strings (from com.android.support:appcompat-v7) appeared in my APK

Tags: android, localization, android-gradle-plugin

In recent builds of an android application I wrote I see the appearance of a lot of file containing translations for several strings that I never added.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="abc_action_bar_home_description">Navigate home</string>
    <string name="abc_action_bar_up_description">Navigate up</string>
    <string name="abc_action_menu_overflow_description">More options</string>
    <string name="abc_action_mode_done">Finished</string>
    <string name="abc_activity_chooser_view_see_all">See all</string>
    <string name="abc_activitychooserview_choose_application">Choose an app</string>
    <string name="abc_searchview_description_clear">Clear query</string>
    <string name="abc_searchview_description_query">Search query</string>
    <string name="abc_searchview_description_search">Search</string>
    <string name="abc_searchview_description_submit">Submit query</string>
    <string name="abc_searchview_description_voice">Voice search</string>
    <string name="abc_shareactionprovider_share_with">Share with</string>
    <string name="abc_shareactionprovider_share_with_application">Share with %s</string>
</resources>
```

Those strings seems to come from the [`android.support.v7.mediarouter.R.string`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/mediarouter/R.string.html) file and that is coherent with the fact that I am using the compatibility support library (But I am not using mediarouter)

I compiled my application with gradle and using Android Studio and in both case (Unsurprisingly since they are both using the same scripts).

How can I get rid of them? That is particularly important because my app is now listed in the Play Store as supporting 56 languages when it actually supports only 2.

I see that it first happened when I first switched from API level 8+ to API level 7+, but now even if I choose an higher API level I still have them.

Comment: Did test what happens if you switch your device to a language that is not supported by your app? (I suspect the app can crash.)

Comment: Luckily (I tested it on an emulator) it does fall back to the default language. Still it is very annoying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This discussion](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62593) on the android bug tracker and this [StackOverflow Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20280872/android-studio-exports-strings-from-support-library-to-apk/20538112#20538112) show how to solve the issue with Android Gradle Plug-in 0.7+.