# Android build.gradle defaultConfig { resConfig "en" } effect on Localization & Distribution in the Google Play Store

Tags: android, localization, apk, distribution, android-support-library

I am using the answer here:
[Android support library increases APK size a lot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21017480/android-support-library-increases-apk-size-a-lot?rq=1)

To reduce the apk size by removing localizations I am not using from the support library as follows:

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    resConfig "en"
}

And it work :)
```

When I upload my apk to Google Play I believe that I would see

> Localizations default
>
> instead of
>
> Localizations default + 73 languages

If this is true, will limiting the Localizations affect/reduce the countries I can distribute too?

To put it clearer, if my apk is localized to english only can I still distribute to all countries?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can. The overview just displays the languages supported in your app. Distribution is independent from this setting.