# How to remove unused resources from libraries?

Tags: android, gradle, android-resources

> At first I know [Remove all unused resources from an android project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6373482/995926), but that is only for projects.

I want to remove unused images from a library like the Google Play Services or the Wearable SDK. I already know that I can remove unwanted languages in gradle by using [`resConfigs`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20280872/995926), but I don't know how to remove images and layouts which I don't use. Is there any way to avoid that they are added?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I almost missed it to write that there is now a nice solution:

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
        }
    }
}﻿
```

This was annouced on [Google+ by Tor Norbye](https://plus.google.com/+TorNorbye/posts/eHsStybrrBf) for the build tools version 0.14.0

Answer (score 2):

Probbably all you need to know about that is in this very good article from Cyril Mottier : 
http://cyrilmottier.com/2014/08/26/putting-your-apks-on-diet/

Read the part about Lint ("Use Lint extensively"), as it's the tool that allow you to remove unused resources.

Hope it helps...

Comment: That is, indeed, a great site. However I have the same problem as in the footnote 3, but there is no automatic fix for that.

Comment: You're right, and I misinterpreted your question. Sadly, I don't think there is any solution for this.