# enable proguard only for remove unused code

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard

My app using some jar libs with too many methods, but in fact used only 2-3 methods from this libs. Total size of this libs more than 2Mb. I don't need all of it and i want to shrink my apk with ProGuard.

I need  to enable ProGuard and configure it only for remove unused code and shrink apk size. but I don't know how. I don't want to obfuscate my app and etc. only shrink final size.

I  try to enable proguard by

```
minifyEnabled true
```

but it got only errors and nothing.

Comment: Please post the resulting errors to help the community answer your question.

Comment: Try [putting `-dontobfuscate`](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html#dontobfuscate) in your ProGuard rules.

Comment: @CommonsWare thank. by your way, i found more solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25843122/how-to-remove-unused-resources-from-libraries thats help.

Answer (score 2):

To only shrink your application you should do the following:

```
release {
  proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
  proguardFile 'proguard-shrink-only.txt'
  proguardFile 'proguard-project.txt'
}
```

The `proguard-shrink-only.txt` should contain the following options:

```
-dontobfuscate
-dontoptimize
```

The `proguard-project.txt` should contain your project specific keep rules that might be needed for classes that are used via reflection.