# How do I remove unused languages in released or signed APK file with Xamarin.Android?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have an android app in google play store developed in Xamarin.Android. It supports 11 Indian languages but when i release the app it shows 85 localization(languages) which is effecting my app ranking. Basically my issue is described in this link [Android Studio exports strings from support library to APK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20280872/android-studio-exports-strings-from-support-library-to-apk). I have googled the issue but found only this solution [How do I remove unused languages from the final APK file with Xamarin.Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32247124/how-do-i-remove-unused-languages-from-the-final-apk-file-with-xamarin-android) which is not working.

How can i keep only specific localization in my release APK?

Comment: Confused, how can manually removing language files from an APK not work?

Comment: Hi @SushiHangover I don't want manual removing of language files because this may cause some issue in my signed apk. I am looking for the way android studio gradle file does like defaultConfig {"en", "de", "es"}.

Comment: You can create these folders by youself like this link.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/resources-in-android/application-localization?tabs=windows