# How do I remove unused languages from the final AAB file with Xamarin.Android?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-app-bundle

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32247124/how-do-i-remove-unused-languages-from-the-final-apk-file-with-xamarin-android) but regarding APK files. Basically, all the localizations from included libraries are exported into the final archive. I've been using for a long time the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34787251/3315714), which implies to extract all files from the APK, remove unwanted resources, and pack everything else into a new APK, and then signing it.

But Google now [requires](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2021/06/the-future-of-android-app-bundles-is.html) to use Android Application Bundles (AAB) when releasing new apps on Google Play Store.

Is It possible to do something similar to AAB archive? I did have a look at the internal structure and I did not find any string resources.

Comment: Four ways to reduce compressed APK download sizes: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle#size-savings-because-of-dynamic-delivery  If you want to shrink your app by removing unused code and resources, you could check the link below. https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#groovy

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT, I am not trying to reduce the app size. I just need to remove certain localizations, so the Google Play Store would not show that my app supports those languages. I am using Xamarin.Android, so using gradle is not an option here.

Comment: You could try to remove it first and then generate the AAB.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT, Could you please suggest how this may be done? As I understand, all localizations are packed in the libraries .dll's. Should I somehow disassemble the .dll, remove localizations, and then assemble it back?

Comment: It may be something wrong when you disassemble the dll. Create a new one would be better.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT, Yes, I've made a simple tool to replace resources in a dll, but the resulted dll didn't work. What do you mean by "Create a new one would be better"? Rebuilding each dll doesn't seem achievable, as I don't have the source code.

Comment: If you do not have the source code, it would be hard to achieve.